# How to pick value based on condition in macros

Tags: vba, excel

I want to compare the data so I have to pick a value based on a condition. The example data that I have is like:

[image]

The condition is:

I want to pick the value of PO NO. that always placed 2 column after text "PO NO."

How do I get that value? After that copy and paste it in another column (example:column A)

Comment: `If MyCellWithPoNo.Value2 = "PO NO." Then MyDesiredValue = MyCellWithPoNo.Offset(ColumnOffset:=2).Value2`. More [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/office/ff840060.aspx).

Comment: @CommonSense I'm sorry I'm very new for knowing macros. May u explained more about that?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how do you want to use those values, if you just want to put them into some continued ranges in current workbook, then I think the Filter function is sufficient, if you want to do some further calculation, you may want to write some VBA code:

1. Press ALT + F11 in your current worksheet.
2. Press ALT + I then press M.
3. Press Ctrl + G to open the "Immediate" window
4. Then write the following lines:

   ```
   Sub myValues()

       Dim rCount As Long
       Dim i As Long

       Let rCount = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Row

       For i = 1 to rCount
           If WorksheetFunction.Trim(ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(i,6).Text) = "PO No." Then
               Debug.Print ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(i,8).Text
           End If
       Next

   End Sub
   ```

Now you could get all the PO NO values in the "Immediate" window.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the value you want using this formula.

> =INDEX(F44:H49,MATCH("PO No.",F44:F49,0),3)

The problem which remains to be solved is how to define the range F44:F49. Your question delivers no hint as to how that should be done. Perhaps knowing where you want to value to appear would offer a clue.

Comment: I have to do it with macros, because after that I have to compare the data with another sheet.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over each cell in the column and gather your post numbers, offsetted by 2 columns, like I mentioned in comments

```
Sub Test()
    Dim WS As Worksheet
    Dim ParamRange As Range
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim Cell As Range
    Dim i As Long

    Set WS = ActiveSheet                                   'or whatever sheet your want


    With WS
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row
        Set ParamRange = .Range("F1:F" & LastRow)
    End With


    For Each Cell In ParamRange                             'iterate over column
        If Cell.Value2 = "PO NO." Then
            i = i + 1
            'Debug.Print to Immediate
            Debug.Print i, CurrentSearch.Offset(ColumnOffset:=2).Value2
            'Paste in "A" column
            CurrentSearch.Offset(ColumnOffset:=-5).Value2 = CurrentSearch.Offset(ColumnOffset:=2).Value2
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

So you just need to collect all `Cell.Offset(ColumnOffset:=2).Value2` values.

Alternatively, without iteration over cells (and faster), but little bit complicated:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim WS As Worksheet
    Dim ParamRange As Range
    Dim CurrentSearch As Range
    Dim FirstSearch As Range
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim Cell As Range
    Dim i As Long

    Set WS = ActiveSheet                                   'or whatever sheet your want


    With WS
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row
        Set ParamRange = .Range("F1:F" & LastRow)
    End With


    'Get first search
    Set CurrentSearch = ParamRange.Find(What:="PO NO.", LookIn:=xlValues, _
            LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
            MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

    If Not CurrentSearch Is Nothing Then
        i = i + 1
        'Debug.Print to Immediate
        Debug.Print i, CurrentSearch.Offset(ColumnOffset:=2).Value2
        'Paste in "A" column
        CurrentSearch.Offset(ColumnOffset:=-5).Value2 = CurrentSearch.Offset(ColumnOffset:=2).Value2
        Set FirstSearch = CurrentSearch

        Do
            'Get next search
            Set CurrentSearch = ParamRange.FindNext(After:=CurrentSearch)

            If Not CurrentSearch Is Nothing Then
                If CurrentSearch.Address = FirstSearch.Address Then Exit Do
                i = i + 1
                'Debug.Print to Immediate
                Debug.Print i, CurrentSearch.Offset(ColumnOffset:=2).Value2
                'Paste in "A" column
                CurrentSearch.Offset(ColumnOffset:=-5).Value2 = CurrentSearch.Offset(ColumnOffset:=2).Value2
            Else
                Exit Do
            End If
        Loop
    End If
End Sub
```

Links:

[Range.Offset](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/office/ff840060.aspx)

[Find last row, column or last cell](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win005.htm)

[.Find and .FindNext in Excel VBA](http://www.siddharthrout.com/2011/07/14/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/)